# Group on different objects values in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB query/aggregation needed: If I have an array, how can I group documents depending on different values in an array? Example:

If I have these objects:

```
> db.respondents.insert({person: 1, responses: [{question: 'How old are you?', response: '18-40 yrs'}, {question: 'What is the brand of your car?', response: 'Fiat'} ] } )
> db.respondents.insert({person: 2, responses: [{question: 'How old are you?', response: '18-40 yrs'}, {question: 'What is the brand of your car?', response: 'Volvo'} ] } )
> db.respondents.insert({person: 3, responses: [{question: 'How old are you?', response: '41-65 yrs'}, {question: 'What is the brand of your car?', response: 'Volvo'} ] } )
> db.respondents.insert({person: 4, responses: [{question: 'How old are you?', response: '41-65 yrs'}, {question: 'What is the brand of your car?', response: 'Volvo'} ] } )
```

And would like to write a query which tells me what car brand respondents own (aka base question) per age group (aka breakdown question)?

So the answer should tell me:

*1 person in  age group '18-40' responded 'Fiat' to question 'What is the brand of you car?'*

*1 person in  age group '18-40' responded 'Volvo' to question 'What is the brand of you car?'*

*2 persons in  age group '41-65' responded 'Volvo' to question 'What is the brand of you car?'*

And IRL:

- There are 100.000+ respondents
- There are about 30 'responses' per respondent
- MongoDb 3.0.9 is used

I've tried numerous ways but won't bore you with my failures....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pitty you don't have MongoDB 3.2, since operators like [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) make this a simple process with a single [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage:

```js
db.respondents.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "responses.question": { 
      "$all": [
        "How old are you?",
        "What is the brand of your car?"
      ]
    } 
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "age": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": { "$filter": {
              "input": "$responses",
              "as": "res",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [ "$$res.question", "How old are you?" ]
              }
            }},
            "as": "res",
            "in": "$$res.response"
          }},
          0
        ]
      },
      "car": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          { "$map": {
            "input": { "$filter": {
              "input": "$responses",
              "as": "res",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [ "$$res.question", "What is the brand of your car?" ]
              }
            }},
            "as": "res",
            "in": "$$res.response"
          }},
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

In earlier versions you need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the content and then conditionally select the required response values via [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```js
db.respondents.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "responses.question": { 
      "$all": [
        "How old are you?",
        "What is the brand of your car?"
      ]
    } 
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$responses" },
  { "$match": { 
    "responses.question": { 
      "$in": [
        "How old are you?",
        "What is the brand of your car?"
      ]
    } 
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "age": {
      "$max": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$responses.question", "How old are you?" ] },
          "$responses.response",
          null
        ]
      }
    },
    "car": {
      "$max": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$responses.question", "What is the brand of your car?" ] },
          "$responses.response",
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "age": "$age",
      "car": "$car"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

But of course it is very possible, and the common results are:

```js
{ "_id" : { "age" : "41-65 yrs", "car" : "Volvo" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "age" : "18-40 yrs", "car" : "Volvo" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "age" : "18-40 yrs", "car" : "Fiat" }, "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: I hereby ignore the SO comment guidelines and write: +1, thanks - you're my hero! Sweetness. Exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Excuse me - meant 'heroine' of course. I bet it wasn't moonlight yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I see no straightforward way to do it. But!
You may do this:

```
db.respondents.aggregate([
  {$unwind:'$responses'},
  {$match:{'responses.question':'How old are you?'}}
]).foreach(function(resp){
  db.responses.update({_id:resp._id},{$set:{ageGroup:resp.responses.response}});
})
```

It could work for some time but then you'll have convenient `ageGroup` field and use it for grouping.

Comment: Of course it's possible and quite straightforward, and there is absolutely no need to write data to another collection. It's better and far more efficient with a modern release, but still can be done in any version without multiple queries or client looping.